# vk sdk android initialize error

Tags: java, android, вконтакте, sdk

На устройстве с android 5 все ок, но на android 4, возникает ошибка при инициализации.  `VKSdk.initialize(this);`

`08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.vk.sdk.VKAccessToken.tokenFromParameters, referenced from method com.vk.sdk.VKSdk.checkAndSetToken
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 62092: Lcom/vk/sdk/VKAccessToken;.tokenFromParameters (Ljava/util/Map;)Lcom/vk/sdk/VKAccessToken;
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.vk.sdk.VKAccessToken.currentToken, referenced from method com.vk.sdk.VKSdk.getAccessToken
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 62088: Lcom/vk/sdk/VKAccessToken;.currentToken ()Lcom/vk/sdk/VKAccessToken;
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 22396 (Unknown) in Lcom/vk/sdk/VKSdk$LoginState;
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.vk.sdk.VKAccessToken.currentToken, referenced from method com.vk.sdk.VKSdk.isLoggedIn
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 62088: Lcom/vk/sdk/VKAccessToken;.currentToken ()Lcom/vk/sdk/VKAccessToken;
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.vk.sdk.VKAccessToken.replaceToken, referenced from method com.vk.sdk.VKSdk.logout
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 62090: Lcom/vk/sdk/VKAccessToken;.replaceToken (Lcom/vk/sdk/VKAccessToken;)Lcom/vk/sdk/VKAccessToken;
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.webkit.CookieManager.removeAllCookies, referenced from method com.vk.sdk.VKSdk.logout
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 15293: Landroid/webkit/CookieManager;.removeAllCookies (Landroid/webkit/ValueCallback;)V
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/vk/sdk/VKAccessToken;)
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/vk/sdk/VKAccessToken;)
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.vk.sdk.VKSdk$1', referenced from method com.vk.sdk.VKSdk.notifyVKTokenChanged
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 8846 (Lcom/vk/sdk/VKSdk$1;) in Lcom/vk/sdk/VKSdk;
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.vk.sdk.VKAccessToken.replaceToken, referenced from method com.vk.sdk.VKSdk.onAccessTokenIsInvalid
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 62090: Lcom/vk/sdk/VKAccessToken;.replaceToken (Lcom/vk/sdk/VKAccessToken;)Lcom/vk/sdk/VKAccessToken;
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.vk.sdk.VKAccessToken.currentToken, referenced from method com.vk.sdk.VKSdk.onActivityResult
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 62088: Lcom/vk/sdk/VKAccessToken;.currentToken ()Lcom/vk/sdk/VKAccessToken;
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve instance field 22390
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.vk.sdk.VKAccessToken.currentToken, referenced from method com.vk.sdk.VKSdk.updateLoginState
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 62088: Lcom/vk/sdk/VKAccessToken;.currentToken ()Lcom/vk/sdk/VKAccessToken;
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method com.vk.sdk.VKAccessToken.currentToken, referenced from method com.vk.sdk.VKSdk.wakeUpSession
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 62088: Lcom/vk/sdk/VKAccessToken;.currentToken ()Lcom/vk/sdk/VKAccessToken;
08-25 07:45:23.045    1143-1143/? I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x574f at 0x19 in Lcom/vk/sdk/VKSdk;.checkAndSetToken
08-25 07:45:23.049    1143-1143/? I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x5776 at 0x34 in Lcom/vk/sdk/VKSdk;.processActivityResult
08-25 07:45:23.049    1143-1143/? I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x5778 at 0x73 in Lcom/vk/sdk/VKSdk;.processActivityResult
08-25 07:45:23.049    1143-1143/? I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x5777 at 0x77 in Lcom/vk/sdk/VKSdk;.processActivityResult
08-25 07:45:23.049    1143-1143/? I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x5778 at 0x8e in Lcom/vk/sdk/VKSdk;.processActivityResult
08-25 07:45:23.049    1143-1143/? I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x5779 at 0x06 in Lcom/vk/sdk/VKSdk;.updateLoginState
08-25 07:45:23.049    1143-1143/? I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x577a at 0x0c in Lcom/vk/sdk/VKSdk;.updateLoginState
08-25 07:45:23.049    1143-1143/? I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x574f at 0x0b in Lcom/vk/sdk/VKSdk;.wakeUpSession
08-25 07:45:23.049    1143-1143/? I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x577b at 0x15 in Lcom/vk/sdk/VKSdk;.wakeUpSession
08-25 07:45:23.053    1143-1143/? W/ResourceType﹕ No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
08-25 07:45:23.053    1143-1143/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4b77648)
08-25 07:45:23.053    1143-1143/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.vk.sdk.VKSdk$LoginState
            at com.vk.sdk.VKSdk.initialize(VKSdk.java:137)
            at com.test.android.test.onCreate(TestApplication.java:73)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4444)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 07:45:24.801    1143-1143/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1143 SIG: 9`

Подключил SDK через Maven

`apply plugin: 'com.test.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.android"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
    compile 'com.vk:androidsdk:1.5.7'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'

}`

Появился другой краш

`08-26 09:23:08.971    5457-5463/? E/jdwp﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
08-26 09:23:08.983    5457-5457/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.webkit.CookieManager.removeAllCookies, referenced from method com.vk.sdk.VKSdk.logout
08-26 09:23:08.983    5457-5457/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 15291: Landroid/webkit/CookieManager;.removeAllCookies (Landroid/webkit/ValueCallback;)V
08-26 09:23:08.983    5457-5457/? W/ResourceType﹕ No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
08-26 09:23:08.995    5457-5457/? I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 14.055MB for 5600012-byte allocation
08-26 09:23:09.099    5457-5457/? I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 23.550MB for 9956856-byte allocation
08-26 09:23:09.143    5457-5457/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.test.android.ui.accounts.LoginActivity$1$1', referenced from method com.test.android.ui.accounts.LoginActivity$1.onClick
08-26 09:23:09.143    5457-5457/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2060 (Lcom/test/android/ui/accounts/LoginActivity$1$1;) in Lcom/test/android/ui/accounts/LoginActivity$1;
08-26 09:23:09.199    5457-5457/? W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-26 09:23:09.203    5457-5457/? E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
08-26 09:23:09.203    5457-5457/? E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
08-26 09:27:02.499    5457-5457/com.test.android W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4b8d648)
08-26 09:27:02.503    5457-5457/com.test.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.test.android.ui.accounts.LoginActivity$1$1
            at com.test.android.ui.accounts.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:71)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Если убираю `'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'` ошибка пропадает.

Comment: А где инициализируете?

Comment: В наследнике класса  Application

Comment: хмм, а в build.gradle у либы точно минимальная сдк правильно прописана?

Comment: да, все там правильно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все дело в Multidex, чтобы он работал нормально на android ниже 5.

Нудно не только `multiDexEnabled true`. А еще `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'`

И в вашем наследнике Application

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Подробнее [Building Apps with Over 65K Methods](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/building/multidex.html)